# How can I modify `sys.path` before python interpreter initializes using Python/C API?

Tags: python, python-c-api, sys

From the [official example](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init_config.html#example), I understand that I can modify `sys.path` before the interpreter initializes using the following code(exception handlings are omitted):

```cpp
PyConfig config;
PyConfig_InitPythonConfig(&config);
PyConfig_Read(&config);
config.module_search_paths_set = 1;
PyWideStringList_Append(&config.module_search_paths, L"/path/to/module");
Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config);
```

However, as indicated in the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init_config.html#c.PyConfig_Read), starting from `python 3.11`, `PyConfig_Read` will not initialize path-related fields in `PyConfig`. My question is: How can I get the default `sys.path` before the interpreter initializes? I need this because I want to set `module_search_paths` in the config and normally I would like to append the path for my custom modules to the default `sys.path`.

I know that I can set `sys.path` after initializing the interpreter, but I hope I can do it before the initialization.

Comment: How about adding paths to *PYTHONPATH*?